# Interactive, incremental fuzzy search for files/directories in Bash?

Tags: bash, vim, autocomplete

I have tried with `z` and `fasd` but none of them seem to provide an incremental fuzzy search like what I have in vim via CtrlP. Is there such a utility for Bash?

I need to navigate to different files/directories (based on my history or maybe complete filesystem) and entry something like "cd bo" and possibly press  then get a list of candidates which match this search and I can choose one of candidates or continue typing to narrow my search.

Comment: Have you tried pressing the Tab key?

Comment: Yes I have, it is not fuzzy and does not cover other directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really check out [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf), a general command line fuzzy-finder that works with bash/zsh/fish, vim, and others.

For example, you can use the `CTRL-T` keybinding in bash like in the gif below (from the fzf wiki page):

[image: Example of how to use fzf]

You can learn about other examples on their [wiki page](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/wiki/examples).

Hope this helps ! :)

Comment: Can you elaborate your answer, it looks like a comment